# MS Access form opens before make table query finishes

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, dao, synchronous

In my access database I have TABLE1 which is a linked table to a SQL 2005 server table. I have a query QUERY1 which selects a subset of TABLE1, manipulates / formats some of its data, and places that data into temporary table TMP_TABLE1 (ie. `SELECT * INTO [TMPTABLE1] FROM [TABLE1]`). I also have a form FORM1 that has TMP_TABLE1 as its recordsource where I can view and manipulate the data.

Here is my code that accomplishes these tasks:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TMPTABLE1"
On Error GoTo 0

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentDb.Execute "QUERY1", dbSeeChanges
DoEvents
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM1", acNormal, , , , acDialog
```

The problem I am having is that my FORM1 tries to open before my QUERY1 finishes processing and I get an error stating my table does not exist. I have always experienced CurrentDb.Execute as a synchronous query and have only recently run into this behaviour. If I place a short pause or a loop waiting for the table to be created before opening the form, my procedure will work correctly.

Unfortunately, this is just one example of the underlying problem which I can't remedy. For example, even if I keep the temporary table and simply delete all records and append all new records, the problem persists. This happens for any instances where I manipulate data in code before displaying it on screen such as INSERT statements, UPDATE statements, DAO.Recordset and ADODB.Recordset objects.

I have tested the compiled and uncompiled client on Windows 7 64-bit, Windows Vista 32-bit and Windows XP 32-bit and the all react the same way. The problem is intermittent and occasionally the query will finish quickly and my form will open correctly but 90% of the time it fails to open.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do? Maybe a setting got changed to run queries differently? Could it be a SQL Server 2005 option/setting I need to change?

EDIT:
Below is the most verbose code I could think of to try and wait for the table to be ready and it is still failing. Some times, my execute procedure throws an error saying that TMPTABLE1 already exists even though I delete it at the start of the function.:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TMPTABLE1"
On Error GoTo 0

Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
wrk.BeginTrans
On Error GoTo TransErr
dbs.Execute "QUERY1", dbSeeChanges Or dbFailOnError
wrk.CommitTrans
TransResume:

Dim waitLoop As Long
Do While TableDefExists("_working_ReceivedMaterials") = False
    waitLoop = GetTickCount
    Do While GetTickCount < waitLoop + 100
        DoEvents
    Loop
Loop

DoCmd.OpenForm "ReceivedMaterials_Entry", acNormal, , , , acDialog

Exit Function
TransErr:
    wrk.Rollback
    GoTo TransResume
```

Comment: Do you have a serious justification for using a make table query (MTQ) instead of a select ? I am seeing daily lots of crappy apps full of MTQ, resulting in tables with half a million unindexed rows. That generally makes an untracable, bloated, and disgusting mess.

Comment: No, I have no particular reason. As I mentioned a similar problem is happening in other areas of my code and I decided to post what I thought was the simplest example of it. This has worked for 3+ years until we recently migrated our backend from Access tables to SQL 2005 Tables. As a set of DELETE/INSERT queries works for this particular example I will end it for now and re-post with a different example of the issue.

Comment: Just a question, since I have little experience on that particular point, but are you sure your beginTrans/commitTrans lines actually do something ? I see no relation between the transaction (applied on wrk) and the query (applied on dbs).

Comment: According to this it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243806(v=office.12).aspx  But to be honest I never really looked to deeply into it or tested it much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access can display strange behaviour sometimes when deleting tables and then re-creating them, therefore I dont' think your code is tripping over itself, the best solution I think is to edit your form and change the recordset to nothing.  Then on your forms "On_Load" event, set the recordset there e.g:

Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.Recordset = "SELECT * FROM TMPTABLE1"

End Sub

Alternatively, do not delete the table, just run "DELETE FROM TMPTABLE1" instead, and then instead of a make table query use "INSERT INTO TMPTABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE1"

Comment: I will mark this as accepted because technically this fixes the particular problem I posted. I am still having issues with other areas my access programs without make-table queries, but I will repost a better example of my overall problem.

Comment: Cheers Micah, I'll give your other issues a look if I see the post

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to execute

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
```

Before opening the form?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb

On Error Resume Next
db.TableDefs.Delete "TMPTABLE1"
On Error GoTo 0

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
db.Execute "QUERY1"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

db.TableDefs.Refresh

DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM1", WindowMode:=acDialog
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: In your new edit you are deleting TMPTABLE1 but testing for the availability of "_working_ReceivedMaterials. Is this correct? Also, is the query you are executing creating an access table or is it a pass through query creating a SQL-Server table? In the latter case you probably would have to re-link the external table.